# Using CSS animation marquee how do I make sure text is exactly off the screen?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using CSS animation marquee. The goal is to have the text enter the right side of the container, then leave the left side of the container, then start over.

The text is a list of list items with variable text length. I cannot figure out how to get the animation to end at the right time. See example below. The two animations go completely in sync, because translateX is relative to the container size.

Instead I want translateX to be relative to the size of the text inside the ul instead, so that each animation starts exactly to the right of the container and ends exactly when all the text has disappeared off the left side of the container.

The start point is correct, but the end point of the animation is not.

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background: pink;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container ul {
  margin: 0;
  animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
}

.container ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><ul>
  <li>text1</li>
</ul></div>

<div class="container"><ul>
  <li>First text</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus commodo risus eget sodales. Sed pulvinar dictum ipsum commodo mollis. Proin consequat vestibulum pellentesque. Integer vel dictum leo. Fusce porttitor orci non tortor cursus, sit amet molestie odio imperdiet. Praesent eleifend, diam sit amet bibendum suscipit, nibh metus volutpat urna, vel vestibulum tortor velit ut nibh. Proin facilisis sagittis felis ut sodales.</li>
  <li>Last text</li>
</ul></div>
```

It seems the "100%" in translateX is relative to the size of the container and not the size of the text being animated. What do I need to change to get the text to disappear completely on the left side of the screen before disappearing?

**Update**

I added the snippet directly to the post instead of using JSFiddle.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer to this, perhaps it's not possible.

I ended up using a JavaScript library to achieve the same functionality: https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee